# Problema con Swiper JS

Tags: javascript, html, swiper

Estoy intentando implementar Swiper en una sección que he creado. Al momento de agregar las clases de swiper solo me genera las flechas de adelante y atrás pero no la acción de poder deslizar mi contenido.

En HTML tengo lo siguiente:

```
    <!-- SwiperJS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/swiper-bundle.min.css">

   <section class="services section" id="services">
      <div class="services-info container_services swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="services_content grid-services swiper-slide">
            <img src="img/Slideshow4.jpg" alt="" class="services-img">
            <div class="services-data">
                <h3>Lorem...</h3>
                <p class="services-description">Lorem...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="services_content grid-services swiper-slide">
            <img src="img/Slideshow4.jpg" alt="" class="services-img">
            <div class="services-data">
                <h3>Lorem...</h3>
                <p class="services-description">Lorem...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="services_content grid-services swiper-slide">
            <img src="img/Slideshow4.jpg" alt="" class="services-img">
            <div class="services-data">
                <h3>Lorem...</h3>
                <p class="services-description">Lorem...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="services_content grid-services swiper-slide">
            <img src="img/Slideshow4.jpg" alt="" class="services-img">
            <div class="services-data">
                <h3>Lorem...</h3>
                <p class="services-description">Lorem...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </section>

    <!-- SwiperJS -->
    <script src="js/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

En JavaScript:

```
let swiper = new Swiper(".services-info", {
  cssMode: true,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
  },
  mousewheel: true,
  keyboard: true,
});
```

¿En parte de mi código estoy agregando mal las clases para que no me de la funcionalidad de desplazamiento?

Answer (score 1):

Debes separar el **div** del wrapper (*swiper-wrapper*) de la paginación y los botones, pues ahora mismo estan dentro del mismo.

Dicho de otro modo, pon un `</div>` por encima de esta línea para cerrar el div con clase *swiper-wrapper*:

```
<div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
```

y borra el `</div>` que aparece después de esta línea de la paginación:

```
<div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
```

Te dejo un ejemplo completo funcional:

```js
let swiper = new Swiper(".services-info", {
  cssMode: true,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
  },
  mousewheel: true,
  keyboard: true,
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<section class="services section" id="services">
  <div class="services-info container_services swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="services_content grid-services swiper-slide">
        <img src="img/Slideshow4.jpg" alt="" class="services-img">
        <div class="services-data">
          <h3>Lorem...</h3>
          <p class="services-description">Lorem...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="services_content grid-services swiper-slide">
        <img src="img/Slideshow4.jpg" alt="" class="services-img">
        <div class="services-data">
          <h3>Lorem...</h3>
          <p class="services-description">Lorem...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="services_content grid-services swiper-slide">
        <img src="img/Slideshow4.jpg" alt="" class="services-img">
        <div class="services-data">
          <h3>Lorem...</h3>
          <p class="services-description">Lorem...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="services_content grid-services swiper-slide">
        <img src="img/Slideshow4.jpg" alt="" class="services-img">
        <div class="services-data">
          <h3>Lorem...</h3>
          <p class="services-description">Lorem...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es por qué en Codepen sí me funciona tu respuesta, pero al agregarlo a mi página, las flechas se muestran al inicio de la página y no en donde inicia el contenido.

Comment: quizás el contexto de tu página estropea algo, algun css, etc... sin el no puedo ayudarte... o quizas la version del swiper... verifica si son los mismos que yo uso